# Multiple document formats for one document library list item

Tags: document-library, library, word, pdf

I'd like to know if it's possible to have a ".doc" and ".pdf" option for a single library list item. The intent being that users can access the document in ".doc" or ".pdf".

Also, how to set this up would be good to know as well.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Each document in a library is self-contained so it can only one format.  But that said, do you have both formats available or is your expectation that the system will some how convert between the two formats?

Comment: Both formats are available. However ideally, if it's possible, the system would convert newer version ".doc" to ".pdf".

Comment: Automatic conversion will require coding and the Word Automation Service or a 3rd party extension.  But, if you manually provide and manage both file formats, you could simply store both file formats in a library and use metadata to group the file sets via a view.  Alternatively, if you use a list you could attach both file formats to a single list item.

Comment: Apologies for the blatant self promotion, but the PDF Converter for SharePoint (<disclaimer>which I worked on</disclaimer>) comes with a 'Download file as PDF' option in the Ribbon. Works for almost any file format. See http://www.muhimbi.com/Products/PDF-Converter-for-SharePoint/Summary.aspx

Comment: Further to these comments here's an article on word to pdf conversion. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff181518(v=office.14).aspx